# How to get particular value from preg_match in php

Tags: php, regex

I need this value from given URL. I write a function in PHP, but could not get proper value.

**URL:**

```
<a href="/search/name?birth_place=Madras,%20Tamil%20Nadu,%20India&amp;ref_=nmbio_ov_3">Madras, Tamil Nadu, India</a>
```

**Function:**

```
function match($regex, $str, $i = 0){
    if(preg_match($regex, $str, $match) == 1)
        return $match[$i];
    else
        return false;
}

$arr = array();<br>
$arr['birthplace'] = trim(match('/&lt;a href="\/search\/name\?birth_place=.+?">(.*?)<\/a>/', '&lt;a href="/search/name?birth_place=Madras,%20Tamil%20Nadu,%20India&amp;ref_=nmbio_ov_3">Madras, Tamil Nadu, India&lt;/a>', 1));
```

Also, I want to get 2 values like whatever matches in () should be stored in array. For example in above expression if I make () 2 times then the function should capture both of the cases.

Comment: what is your expected out for the above url ? plz put that down in the question as well

Comment: I need "Madras, Tamil Nadu, India" value have put in () in regex.

Comment: Are you trying to fetch `birth_place` value from url?

Comment: @Pradeep did the answer work for you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this approach ( [run here](https://ideone.com/P7oUhe) )

```
$re = '/birth_place=\K[^&]+/';
$str = '<a href="/search/name?birth_place=Madras,%20Tamil%20Nadu,%20India&ref_=nmbio_ov_3">Madras, Tamil Nadu, India<\\/a>';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
$arr=explode(',%20',$matches[0][0]);
foreach($arr as $key=>$value) 
$arr[$key] = preg_replace('/%20/','',$arr[$key]);
print_r($arr);
```